# Allow anonymous uploads to S3 but me owner of file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I have this scenario, and been trying to figure it out for some time. The deal is that I have an S3 bucket, where anyone can ONLY upload to the bucket anonymously i.e. without login. So they only have write permissions - but cannot view or do anything else. When the item is added to the bucket, I can then go in and view it, download it, edit it etc - so full permissions (I am the bucket owner).

Issue: I have set a policy that allows anonymous uploads to my bucket, and then lets me see the items in S3 bucket - however I do not have permissions to do anything with the file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "allow-anon-put",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "*"
           },
           "Action": "s3:PutObject",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket123/*",
           "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                   "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
               }
           }
       },
       {
           "Sid": "deny-other-actions",
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "NotPrincipal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123:root"
           },
           "NotAction": [
               "s3:PutObject",
               "s3:PutObjectAcl"
           ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket123/*"
       }
   ]
}
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated... or is there a better way of writing a policy to achieve this?

Comment: You *really* should not be allowing anonymous uploads.  There's probably a better way to accomplish your ultimate objective, but you haven't mentioned what that actually is.  Your second policy statement is unnecessary.  Nobody can do those things unless you allow them to.

Comment: The objective is to allow annonymous uploads, but for the bucket owner to have full control over the file once its in s3

Comment: I understand that, but the question is *"why?"*  It's not a best practice to allow anonymous uploads.  At a minimum, a malicious user could overwrite your objects at will.

Comment: I completely agree with the above. But its something I need to prove works.

Comment: Change the first one to   `"Action": [ "s3:PutObject",  "s3:PutObjectAcl" ]` and remove the second statement entirely.  Upload with the header `x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control` and it should work.

Comment: @M.Glatki I dont think you understood the aim?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify @sqlbot's answer, use this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-anon-put",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket123/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This says: *Allow anyone to put an object in this bucket and set the Access Control List, but only if they have specified `bucket-owner-full-control` when uploading the object*.

Then, users need to include this header in their upload command:

```
x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control
```

Or, they use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` (which will set the header to the above).

If they do not include this header, the upload will be rejected.