# AccessDenied on AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

When I run a simple select * query on AWS Athena I get an access denied error.

The query is:

```
select * from sensor.sensordata
```

The Schema is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sensor.sensordata (
  sig string,
  `data` struct<`iat`:timestamp,
  `sub`:string,
  tMax: float,
  tMin: float,
  `tAvg`: float,
  `hAvg`: float,
  hMin: float,
  hMax: float
  >
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/data/';
```

The error I get (IDs shortened) is that a file can not be read:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; 
Request ID: B0048904...; S3 Extended Request ID: CKchfW8...), S3 Extended Request ID: 
CKchfW8... (Path: s3://mybucket/data/sensor=01235EFD886C7DF1EE/t=1561513414.json)
```

However I even made the bucket policy public for everyone:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Beside the bucket policy I also have in the ACL the standard full access to the bucket owner, which is the same Account I run my Athena Query from. I run my query in the AWS Management Console.

Not sure if related: AWS Glue Crawler is not able to read the files. But can list them, I get an error for every file.

What can I do to make the query work?

Comment: Can you test whether you can access the object by using the AWS CLI? For example, `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/data/sensor=01235EFD886C7DF1EE/t=1561513414.json .` Also, how were these files created? I wonder if they came from a different account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein very good questions! Thank you for your help. For s3 cp I get "fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden" (I use the same User as for Athena). This files are created by the IoT sensor, which does a HTTP Push without authentication. I'm not able to change the rights on the object. The User I use is the root account.

Comment: So, it seems you do not have access to the objects in the Amazon S3 bucket! If it is your bucket and you are using the root login, then the only cause would be that the objects are being created without `bucket-owner-full-access` permission. This is normally only an issue if objects are created from a different AWS account. The `Access Denied` error can also occur if an object does not exist but you do not have permission to access the object. It's a way of hiding whether or not a file exists from people who aren't allowed to know.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have the same problem but in my case I do set the acl to bucket-owner-full-control when copying object between accounts and I am seeing the account Canonical ID in the object permissions with read and write permissions set to Yes! But still getting forbidden error. When I upload the file to the same path in my bucket manually then it works using the same IAM role/permissions! Is there any explanation for this? can it be restricted through SCPs?

Comment: @Nisman Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in general is not AWS Athena, but the way I upload the files to S3

I do upload the data from an IoT-device and do this over an anonymous PUT-request. This might be not very secure, but for my use case it’s OK. But as John Rotenstein wrote in a comment on the question, if you do not set `bucket-owner-full-access` to the upload, Athena will no be able to access the files.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you can only fix this on the client side. On the AWS side you can enforce the Client to do so (see also John on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402903/55070), but not change it on the aws side.

**So in short:** If you to an anonymous upload with HTTP to S3 you have to set `bucket-owner-full-access` otherwise AWS Athena can not access the data no matter what ACL settings you use.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't show us your table definition, but I suspect that Athena is wanting to list the contents of the path to discover what files exist, so it can read through them.

The policy only grants permission to Put and Get objects, not to List the bucket. Try adding `ListBucket` permission.

By the way, it's a **really bad idea** to use a Bucket Policy like this since you are making your content public. Instead, the permission should be assigned to the credentials (eg IAM User) that is calling Athena. That way, the bucket is not public.

Comment: This is correct, you need `s3:ListBucket` permission to run Athena queries.

Comment: Thank you very much John. I know it's a bad idea, its just for testing. I also have an IAM User in the ACL, but this does not help. ListBucket is a good idea, but it did not help to solve the problem. I still get the same error. I extended my question a bit, I hope this might help.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer helps resolve similar error: ```AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;```

Answer (score 2):

Your policy is missing ListBucket access which is required for Athena to list the contents of the bucket before get/put object.

Below policy should work.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "S3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kannan! ListBucket is a good idea, but it did not help to solve the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, try accessing the bucket via aws cli. 'aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/data/'.
If you get access denied, then create the policy in IAM and attach it to your user account. Then give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/identity-and-access-management-in-athena.html) point to this example managed policy [AWSQuicksightAthenaAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/awsquicksightathenaaccess-managed-policy.html)to show all the permissions required for SQL clients and BI tools. It is for AWS QuickSight but the permissions are applicable to other tools as well.

Specifically for S3 permissions it has this:

```
{
  Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-athena-query-results-*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The resource in that policy is an S3 ARN pattern that will match all buckets used as the default location for your Athena query results. If you have changed the default location bucket then you should apply similar permissions for that bucket.

### Notes

- You don't need a `Principal` in a policy that is attached to a group/user.
- The Actions `PutObject` and `GetObject` apply to *objects* in s3, not *buckets*, so the resource `"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"` does not need these permissions
- The Quicksight managed policy uses a pattern that will include both the bucket and all the objects in it, so it mixes both bucket *and* object Actions together which works but is not very specific.
- If you use `Permission Boundaries` for your IAM Groups / Users then make sure that is not restricting access to the bucket. I made the mistake of using the Quicksight policy as the permission boundary at the same time as using a custom bucket location, and the permission boundary prevented my additional S3 policy from working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include glue cloudformation access when moving from partitioning from s3 to athena:

`"s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads", "s3:AbortMultipartUpload", "s3:CreateBucket", "s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetBucketLocation", "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts", "athena:ListApplicationDPUSizes", "athena:ListWorkGroups", "athena:ListDataCatalogs", "athena:ListExecutors", "athena:ListEngineVersions", "glue:*" "athena:*" on Resources: "arn:aws:glue:*:RefAccountNumber:*", "arn:aws:s3:::aws-athena-query-results-*" "arn:aws:athena:eu-west-1:RefAccountNumber:workgroup/*" "arn:aws:athena:eu-west-1:RefAccountNumber:datacatalog/*"`

The last ones are specifically important for where athena unloads query results in S3. My use-case was redshipt -> s3 unload followed by s3 -> athena via Apache Hudi incremental loading. It seemed like the glue crawler was outside of the infrastructure but the error was:

> Detail:Amazon Athena experienced a permission error. Please provide proper permission and submitting the query again.